# How to use amixer to change the volume in pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control

I suspect that the volume of pulseaudio is off so I want to use amixer to turn it up from the command line. Can I do this? The amixer syntax is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 10):

I use this:

mute/unmute:

```
amixer -q -D pulse set Master toggle
```

Raise volume:

```
amixer -q -D pulse set Master 5%+ unmute
```

Lower volume:

```
amixer -q -D pulse set Master 5%- unmute
```

`-D pulse`: to make sure we are using pulseaudio (optional)
`unmute`:   so we do not accidentally raise the volume in muted state and be surprised when unmuting

Answer (score 1):

Try these, for example:

```
amixer set Master 5%+ -q

amixer set Master 5%- -q
```

... and experiment with other percentages.